# Visualization Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to know which component is what allows us to insert video game posters with other data.

[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lawku.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In that demo report they are not importing or storing the image  Power BI, they are using a multi-card visual with an image URL, that will display the image from the URL reference.

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/xWLXANXnIlQ) on how to do it.